# JVM crashes while image conversion using javax.media.jai

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jai, jvm-crash

In our app, we use javax.media.JAI library to scale and improve image

But sometimes (1 out of 10 times), it is causing the VM to crash

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdb6f49140b, pid=2153, tid=140580255180544
#
# JRE version: 6.0_22-b22
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.10.4
# Distribution: Fedora release 16 (Verne), package fedora-61.1.10.4.fc16-x86_64
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgs.so+0x16940b]  s_DCT_set_defaults+0x8b
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/share/tomcat/hs_err_pid2153.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Adding logs to code did help to nail down the exact line

```
                DebugHelper.errorLog("Start transformImage2");
        List modImages = new ArrayList();
        PageImage page = new PageImage();

        // generate rendered image.
        RenderedOp im = JAI.create("fileload", image.getFile()
                .getAbsolutePath());

        // get the width and height of original image.
        float width = im.getWidth();
        float height = im.getHeight();

        // improve the quality of image.
        DebugHelper.errorLog("Improving quality of image");
        RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
```

"Start transformImage2" gets printed but "Improving quality of image" does not. So we know it is in those 3-4 lines. Additionally from hs_err* file it points to float width = im.getWidth();

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.initJPEGImageReader()J+0
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.(Ljavax/imageio/spi/ImageReaderSpi;)V+174
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavax/imageio/ImageReader;+5
j  javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance()Ljavax/imageio/ImageReader;+2
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next()Ljavax/imageio/ImageReader;+16
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec$ImageIOJPEGImageDecoder.(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V+26
j  com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec$ImageIOJPEGImageDecoder.(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/image/codec/jpeg/JPEGCodec$1;)V+2
j  com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/sun/image/codec/jpeg/JPEGImageDecoder;+6
j  com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImage.(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/media/jai/codec/ImageDecodeParam;)V+35
j  com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(I)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+29
j  com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/awt/image/renderable/ParameterBlock;Ljava/awt/RenderingHints;)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+184
j  com.sun.media.jai.opimage.JPEGRIF.create(Ljava/awt/image/renderable/ParameterBlock;Ljava/awt/RenderingHints;)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+4
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor740.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+48
J  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+12
j  javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(Ljavax/media/jai/OperationRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/awt/image/renderable/ParameterBlock;Ljava/awt/RenderingHints;)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+35
j  com.sun.media.jai.opimage.StreamRIF.create(Ljava/awt/image/renderable/ParameterBlock;Ljava/awt/RenderingHints;)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+191
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor740.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+48
J  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+12
j  javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(Ljavax/media/jai/OperationRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/awt/image/renderable/ParameterBlock;Ljava/awt/RenderingHints;)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+35
j  com.sun.media.jai.opimage.FileLoadRIF.create(Ljava/awt/image/renderable/ParameterBlock;Ljava/awt/RenderingHints;)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+158
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor740.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+48
J  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+12
j  javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(Ljavax/media/jai/OperationRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/awt/image/renderable/ParameterBlock;Ljava/awt/RenderingHints;)Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;+35
j  javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(Z)Ljavax/media/jai/PlanarImage;+171
J  javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering()V
j  javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getWidth()I+1
j  com.myapp.helpers.conversion.DocumentConverter.transformImage(Lcom/myapp/helpers/conversion/PageImage;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/myapp/helpers/conversion/ImageSetting;)Ljava/util/List;+39
j  com.myapp.helpers.conversion.DocumentConverter.convertDocuments(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/myapp/helpers/conversion/ImageSetting;)Ljava/util/Map;+597
J  com.myapp.helpers.conversion.ConversionTask.run()V
```

So I have a few questions

1. What is (can be) exact cause of the problem?
2. Why does the error not occur all the time, same image gets converted successfully at times and fail at others?
3. How to solve (ofcourse :) ?

Comment: are you maybe trying to read a corrupted image? also: do you have to use JAI? why not just use ImageIO?

Comment: @kritzikratzi, the same image was uploaded successfully after restarting server, so I am sure this is not because of image. I can go for a new library but I will need to justify it to the client (find out exact issue and make sure there is no fix available). Unfortunately I do not find any details about similar bug on the Internet.

Comment: you won't find out the exact issue ever. the jdk is a big ass thing and you're using a weird one too... there's lots of room for weird bugs like this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest checking the [subsequent JVM releases](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

```
JRE version: 6.0_22-b22
```

is relatively old and there are successive JRE 6 releases, plus (of course) Java 7. I suspect that a later version is a simple way of mitigating this issue.

Comment: Thanks Brian for reply. Moving to new JRE looks like a good option, but I need to find out the exact issue first, to make sure moving to new JRE has fixed it. My problem is that same image causes the server to crash and uploads fine the next time.

Comment: "sounds like a good option"? DO IT! it takes ten minutes, and if this fixed your problem you'll know. 
also break away from the webapp thing, just take the code from above in a for loop and throw it in a command line app. the fileupload part doesn't seem to be causing troubles anyways.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i feel silly explaining you how to solve problems, 
but here's what i would do:

1. stop looking for the error in your code, it's not there
2. find out in which line EXACTLY your program crashes. 
   start disabling lines and see if it still crashes.
3. upgrade involved components. the ghostview library first, then jdk, then the os.
4. start switching components. i've always had trouble with the open source jdk, 
   maybe try switching to the proprietary oracle one for a bit. then try a different os.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set heap size

Refer
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/

Comment: I would not normally expect a memory issue to manifest itself as a JVM crash - rather an OutOfMemoryError